# Removing specific parts of string

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings that are like `FFS\D46_24\43_2` I want to return the text between the first backslash and last underscore. In case of above example, I want to get `D46_24\43`

I tried the code below but it throws argument out of range exepction:

```
    public string GetTestName(string text)
    {
        return text.Remove(
            text.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            ,
            text.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter is a count, not an ending index. Additionally, the correct method to isolate part of a string is `Substring` and not `Remove`. So you have to write it as

```
var start = text.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var end = text.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

// no error checking: assumes both indexes are positive
return text.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter is not the end index - it should be the number of characters to remove.

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx) for this overload.

```
int startIndex = text.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
int endIndex = text.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

return text.Remove(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for regular expressions.

```
var regex = new Regex( @"\\(.+)_" );
var match = regex.Match( @"FFS\D46_24\43_2" );

if( match.Success )
{
    // you can loop through the captured groups to see what you've captured
    foreach( Group group in match.Groups )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( group.Value );
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and now you have two problems. ;-) You're using `Groups[1]` - what if the input string was `@"FFS\D46-24\43_2"`?

Comment: @DanPuzey True and good point - just providing an example in this situation.  I'll re-write it to be more safe.

Answer (score 1):

use regex:

```
Match re = Regex.Match("FFS\D46_24\43_2", @"(?<=\\)(.+)(?=_)");
if (re.Success)
{
    //todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Substring instead of Remove.
Try this:

```
public static string GetTestName(string text)
    {
        int startIndex = text.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        int endIndex = text.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string: no \\ or _ found in it.");

        if (startIndex == text.Length - 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid string: the first \\ is at the end of it.");

        return text.Substring(startIndex + 1, 
                              endIndex - startIndex - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = @"FFS\D46_24\43_2";
int startIndex = text.IndexOf("\\", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
    lastIndex  = text.LastIndexOf("_", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

return text.Substring(startIndex + 1, lastIndex-startIndex-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of string.Remove() is the number of elements you want to remove, not the upper index up to which you want to remove.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx

edit: and as others have noted, you want to use Substring(), not Remove()

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.71%29.aspx